# LocalSettings.php not readable(MediaWiki,Xampp)

Tags: php, xampp, mediawiki

Installed Xampp and tried to integrate MediaWiki to it.
At the end of the installation it says
"LocalSettings.php not readable."
"Please correct the file Permissions."
Using OS X Yosemite 10.10
The current file permissions retrived using

> echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('LocalSettings.php')), -4);

is 0640 meaning read and write to owner and read to owner's group and nothing for else

When I try to change permission by

> chmod("LocalSettings.php",0644);

it shows

> Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mediawiki/two.php on line 2

Where two.php is file using which i am accessing permission to LocalSettings.php.

What should i do?

Comment: Not enough information: What OS are you using? Does the file exist? If so, what are the permissions on LocalSettings.php?

Comment: look for edits @Barett

Comment: try `chmod 644 LocalSettings.php` instead

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issues you are experiencing can be resolved [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php).

But try these first:

```
chmod 600
```

**or**

```
chmod 640
```

If 600 does not work.

**EDIT**

You should perform chmod in a terminal session: Applications > Other > Terminal

Then navigate to the folder in which LocalSettings.php is located and run:

```
sudo chmod xxx "LocalSettings.php
```

Where xxx is the mode (644 by your edit).